# Django Filter taking list of foreign key model

Tags: django

I have this two model Route and Project and a relation models:

```
class ProjectRoute(models.Model):
    #Fk
    project                     = models.ForeignKey(Project, null = False, on_delete = CASCADE)
    route                       = models.ForeignKey(Route, null = False, on_delete = CASCADE)
```

Having project ID I want to retrieve a list of routes.

```
relations = ProjectRoute.objects.filter(project__id = project_id)
```

With this filter, I have a list of ProjectRoute. What I whant is the queryset of only route.
Something like this (that doesn't work):

```
routes = ProjectRoute.objects.filter(project__id = project_id).value_list(route)
```

Is it possible?

**EDIT:**

This is the code now. I want to remove FOR:

```
routes_relations           = ProjectRoute.objects.filter(project__id = project_id)
routes = []
for rr in routes_relations:
    routes.append(rr.route)
return routes
```

Comment: That is you want to retrieve `Route`s by `project_id`, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to retrieve all ***`Route`*** s associated with a *`project_id`* id, use the below query

```
Route.objects.filter(projectroute__project_id=project_id).distinct()
```

Comment: It works. I think Django is smart enough to know that Route has a relations with Project thanks to RelationsModels and allow us to make query directly in the model.